# How to set Item height depending on FlatList height

Tags: react-native

I have a flatList with pagination defined as follows:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={{height: `${100 * items.length}%`}}
        data={items}
        horizontal={false}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={200}
        pagingEnabled
        decelerationRate='fast'
        renderItem={onRenderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
      />
```

`renderItem` is defined as follows:

```
const onRenderItem = (data: ListRenderItemInfo<any>) => {
    return (
      <View style={{height: `${100/items.length}%`}>
        // view contents goes here
      </View>
    );
  };

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#251818',
  },
```

With the previous code, paging is broken because the FlatList items' height do not map correctly to the visible part of the FlatList. In other words, each time I try to switch from one item to another, parts of the previous item are shown (and the current item is not displayed entirely)

Comment: Not sure if this is why but your height calculations seem strange to me. (1) if the container height is `100 * x` then each item should have height `100` (as opposed to your  `100/x`. (2) The other strange thing is you're using both flex and heights. Try just sticking to flex by giving each rendered item a `flex: 1`, essentially giving them all the same space to render.